# Sleep inside JavaScript web worker without sacrificing CPU resources

Tags: javascript, web-applications, resources, sleep, web-worker

Overview:
Our company has a need for web application that has access to local resources (RS232 / serial devices). After some research and POC we've discarded options like ActiveX, Java Applets and  decided to create local application (written in C# which will be later transofmed to a service and distributed to the customers) that reads serial data and serves them over HTTP protocol (simple TCP server answering necessary headers + plain serial data). Then the web application does AJAX to 'http://localhost:8080' reading those data.

All this is done in a web worker in a while loop posting message to the main thread filling it in a form's input element. By serving static content I am able to get decent performance. On an older Intel Dual Core (not Core 2 Duo) 1,6GHz CPU in Chrome 13 on Windows there are 300-350 iterations per second and 5 - 9% CPU taken by the web worker thread.

**Q:** What I want to achieve now is to throttle polling interval in the web worker by inserting some sort of sleep() function after each ajax request, e.g. experiment with 100ms in the beginning.

What would be the best solution without sacrificing CPU resources in the thread?

Note: I could insert some delay in the TCP server code as the last resort.

EDIT:

I need to sleep inside worker. Example (oversimplified for clarity):

```
AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();
while (true) {
  AJAX.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8080", false);
  AJAX.send(null);
  var ean = AJAX.responseText;
  if (ean != '') { postMessage(ean); }
  /* NEED TO SLEEP HERE WHETHER THE RESPONSE WAS SENT OR NOT */
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using WebSockets for a real TCP connection. Just implement a websocket http server in C#

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be the [WebSocket API](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). So, you can attach a event listener in your web application and fire it from C# every time you need some action.

Comment: I can imagine a problem when the connection breaks (service restart, TCP connection timeout, etc.). I hope there is some kind of KeepAlive and DeadPeerDetection. Will I have to reregister the event-handler? How hard it would be to implement this in Linux (in contrast to simple TCP HTTP server that can be done in Perl, Python even in Bash.

Comment: Let's keep it simple please. No websocket server running ASP.net @ IIS server. We're thinking of running this on pretty lightweight workstations with posibility to port to Linux and maybe OS X.

Comment: Also, this web worker thread is supposed to run whole day (sometimes more than 12 hours) as the web app will be available offline (html5).

Comment: @Slavius oh I thougth you were using C#. A lightweight webserver would be node.js using socket.io. Socket.IO is the most stable websocket server and it supports auto re-connect. [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I currently use C# as it was the fastest way to prove the concept. However as it will be ported do Linux and probably Mac OS we will have find the most universal and cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no sleep, or wait, function in javascript - but you can emulate one with the use timeouts and callbacks. ("Jumping" to the rest of your code through a callback function - and placing the call in a setTimeout method).

EDIT:

You can do something like this,

```
AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();
var myInterval = setInterval( function(){
    AJAX.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8080", false);
    AJAX.send(null);
    var ean = AJAX.responseText;
    if (ean != '') { postMessage(ean); }
},120);
```

Now if you don't awnt to wait for the first call, place it outside of the interval (so it is ran instantly) and then call the interval again as it is written above.

Comment: As far as I was able to find out setTimeout is a method of window which is not accessible in web worker :(

Comment: Look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_web_workers

  "Workers can use timeouts and intervals just like the main thread can.  This can be useful, for example, if you want to have your worker thread run code periodically instead of nonstop.

See setTimeout(), clearTimeout(), setInterval(), and clearInterval() for details." It seems to suggest that those functions are usable. I have not much experience with webworkers so I can't be of much help only do some side-research. Have you tried this?

Comment: I did try to use it, however was not able to notice any difference so I assumed it does not work so I searched and saw that setTimeout belongs to window object and by looking at the docs (somewhere) I read that window object is not accessible inside web worker. Anyways, I will dig deeper into it. Thanks

Comment: I just tried it with a very simple web worker and the setTimeout function works (in Chrome 12 and firefox 4). I uploaded this very very simple example here.  http://isqueel.com/index_webworkerTest.html (just a timeout before post message)

Comment: Seems to work for you however I may not send anything back to the main thread unless there were some data read already. How do I call setTimeout without function being called after a timeout?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I feel a bit lost. If you provide some more info on what you want to delay I will do my best to help you out.

Comment: Hello please check my reply again, I replaced the while(true) loop with an Interval. I believe it should work.

Comment: What if the AJAX.open and AJAX.send won't finish under 120 ms? Will the anonymous method be interrupted? (sorry I don't have enough time to play with it right now as I'm working on another part of the project.)

Comment: No this code won't wait for the ajax request to be completed. If you want that to happen you can prevent call the, same functin again through a setTimeout in the error and success handlers (therefore, sending the request, waiting for it to complete (fail or success), and 120ms later resend a request. If you want I can edit my code and add that scenario as well.

Comment: Please do so as I currently can't imagine how that could work according to my requirements. Thank you.